# What does "Obsever<Float>" do in the assignment of a lambda to a variable, such as in "val somevar = Observer<Float> { ..... }"

Tags: kotlin, lambda

I'm learning Android programming with Kotlin. I do have a basic understanding of OO programming and lambdas.

The general syntax to assign a lambda to a variable, as I understand it, is as follows:

```
val somevar [: ( parm1-type [, parm2-type [,...] ] -> return-type ] = { [ parm1 [, parm2 [,...] ] -> ] stmt1 [; stmt2 [;...] ] }
```

The current example in the book has a variable called `resultObserver` which is initialized with a lambda:

```
val resultObserver = Observer<Float> { result -> resultText.text = result.toString() }
```

What is the `Observer<Float>` in that statement doing? It doesn't seem to fit the syntax above. What am I missing?

Here is some more of the coding sample in case it matters to answer my question:

```
class MainFragment : Fragment() {
    ...
    private lateinit var viewModel: MainViewModel

    override fun onCreateView( ...
    }

    override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)
        viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this).get(MainViewModel::class.java)

        val resultObserver = Observer<Float> { result -> resultText.text = result.toString() }

        viewModel.getResult().observe( viewLifecycleOwner, resultObserver )
        ...
    }

}
```

```
class MainViewModel : ViewModel() {
    ...
    private var result: MutableLiveData<Float> = MutableLiveData()
    ...

    fun getResult() : MutableLiveData<Float> {
        return result
    }
}
```

Comment: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/fun-interfaces.html#sam-conversions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating an anonymous instance of `Observer` interface

```
//Observer from documentation
public interface Observer<T> {
    /**
     * Called when the data is changed.
     * @param t  The new data
     */
    void onChanged(T t);
}

//**** traditional way ****

class FloatObserver: Observer<Float>{
    override fun onChanged(t: Float?) {
        
    }
}

val resultObserver = FloatObserver()

//**** lambda way ****
//doing it in lambda way, as interface has single method, you can use it as lambda 
val resultObserver = Observer<Float> { t ->    }
```